# How to remove underline in <a> tag which having an image in IE7

Tags: html, css

```
<a id="link" href="#">
     <img id="image1" src="image1.jpg">
</a
```

I am applying style as

```
#link
{
text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

I am getting underline around image in IE7. Please help me to remove that underline.

Comment: _"underline around image"_ ~ **under** lines don't go _around_.  Are you getting an underline or a border?

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple Fix:

Remove underline.

```
a, a img {text-decoration: none;}
```

Generally, IE 7 adds an underline inheriting from the `a` tag. So, resetting it will solve the problem.

---

In your question, **around the image**, so is it a border? If so, use this:

```
a, a img {text-decoration: none; border: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `text-decoration` property of the `img` to `none`.

```
a img{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5SUaa/3/

Answer (score 0):

`a#link {text-decoration:none;}` should do the trick.

Comment: No such thing as `decoration`.

Comment: I will correct myself, the above will unset any decoration of the link set by default such as undrline within the link only. if your image has border that you can add the following img {border:none;} as general or img#image1 {border:none;}, the last one is specific for id set in image.

Comment: Please don't use comments where you should be editing your posting.  And I still can't find any reference to a CSS property simply called `decoration`.

Comment: sorry meant text-decoration

Answer (score 0):

Try this

a, a img {text-decoration: none !important; border: 0;}